# Excluding java fields from the mapped XML file

Tags: java, xml, marshalling

I have a java class which I need to convert to an XML file. But I have some fields in that class which should not come in the XML file.

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar endDate;
@XmlElement(name = "due_date")
@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar dueDate;
@XmlElement(name = "main_destination")
protected String mainDestination;

private String _productCode;
```

from the above fields I need to exclude "_productCode" from the XML file generated. But having the productCode field defined like this and also the getter and setter in the same way, i'm still getting that in the XML file. can some one please suggest a way to do this.

thanks...

Comment: Try the transient modifier: private transient String _productCode;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`@XmlTransient` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html):

```
@XmlTransient
private String _productCode;
```